# I can't figure out what this transistor example circuit does. Any ideas?

Tags: transistors, current, circuits

I was looking up transistor circuit examples and stumbled upon this one.  I can't figure out what this circuit does.

[image: Transistor Example circuit]

[Image source - page 5 in this PDF](https://jmp.sh/s/NzqVgLKHKRImrUxMU6rL).

Sorry, the original document (linked above) is in Indonesian. I'll try to translate the important points.

- FG wave = square wave with F = 120Hz, and Vpp = 3
- Ic = Ue / Re

and the device on the right is a dual trace CRT oscilloscope.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what the device to the right is . . .

The circuit creates a high-peak-current spike that tapes off to a lower continuous value.

Initially, C is discharged with 0 V across it.  With the switch in position 1, R2 is bypassed.  When the function generator (FG) square wave output goes high, the transistor (Q1?) conducts as a saturated switch.  The current through Q1 is limited only by the equivalent series resistance (ESR) of C, so it is a large, fast spike.  Essentially, C is a dead short across R1.  As C charges up, the voltage across it increases, the current through it decreases, and the current through R1 increases.  When C is fully charged, the current through it is 0 A, and R1 limits the collector current to a steady-state value as long as the FG output is high.

With the switch in position 2. R2 limits the peak amplitude of the spike.

Note that this description assumes that the FG output voltage is high enough to hold Q1 in saturation even with a voltage drop across the 1 ohm emitter resistor (R3?).  This might be affected by a current path from Y1 to Y2.  Also, the voltage across R3 will work to decrease the current through R1 and R2, affecting the shape of the current spike waveform.

UPDATE:

With the added information, it now looks more like a linear ramp generator rather than a spike.